# Multiple UICollectionView in one controller

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a view set up with two UICollectionViews. Each of these views has an array backing it with different sizes. collection1 is backed by array1, and collection2 is backed by array2. The problem is, what ever number is returned for collection1 from numberOfItemsInSection is being applied to both collection views.

For instance, if array1 is size 4 and array2 is size 5, both collections will show 4 elements. If array1 is size 5 and array2 is size 4, when I scroll collection2 all the way it calls cellForItemAtIndexPath with an itemIndex of 5 for collection2 and I get an NSRangeException.

How can I make each collectionView use it's own size?

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    if(view == self.colleciton1){
        return self.array1.count;
    } else if (view == self.collection2){
        return self.array2.count;
    }

    return 0;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if(cv == self.collection1){
        CharacterCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:FIRST_CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.label.text = self.array1[indexPath.item];
        return cell;
    } else if (cv == self.collection2){
        EpisodeCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:SECOND_CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.label.text = self.array2[indexPath.item];
        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I've included a git repo with a project illustrating the problem.

git@github.com:civatrix/MultipleCollectionViews.git

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the same layout object for each collection. In retrospect that makes sense, but you have to make sure you create different layouts for each collectionView.

Comment: How can I use different layouts for each CollectionView? I have a custom layout and doesnt let me use it

Comment: i have same issue....i have used two different layout for two collection view...but still have same error

Comment: exactly! I used the same layout instance for multiple cvs and it gave me wrong result. I resolved by using separate layouts for each cv

Comment: How can i create different layouts for each collectionView?

Answer (score 5):

Probably it would be easier to use ContainerViews and have two separate UICollectionView Controllers for each UICollectionView

Comment: Good suggestion. That would both make the code clearer and make it more modular so you could reuse the individual collection view controllers in different places.

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work. Are self.colleciton1 and self.collection2 IBOutlets? If so, can you double check that they are hooked up correctly?

Comment: Everything is hooked up correctly, I see some of the elements in each collection view.