# SVPullToRefresh crash with UICollectionView and iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, infinite-scroll

I have this collection view which I want to add SVPullToRefresh's Infinite Scroll feature.

The collection view is set with 1 section and `n` (variable) cells.

I included the feature:

```
  __weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;

  [_collection addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^ {
    [weakSelf loadNextPage];
  }];
```

And the collection view shows perfectly as it should. On iOS 6, the method `-loadNextPage` is called normally and the app runs with no problems. On the other hand, on iOS 7, when the VC is about to call the method, the app crashes with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x1ca8fc50> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}'
```

I've been trying to find what exactly is the piece of code, or which part in the code flow the exception appears, but I can't find it.

**Edit:** added some code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  ProductCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  Product *product = [_productList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
  [cell setName:[product name]];
  [cell setImage:[product imageURL]];
  [cell setPrice:[product formattedPrice]];
  [cell setDistance:[product formattedDistance]];
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: We also couldn't find it unless you put some of your code here for analysing?

Comment: What parts specifically?

Comment: tableView's cellForIndexPath if you are implementing tableview.

Comment: It's not a table, it's a UICollectionView.

Comment: Ok, do you implement (UICollectionViewCell *)cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in CellForItemAtIndexPath, It appeared as if something iOS7.0 specific changes has broken the addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler implementation.

Comment: Refer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339030/uicollectionview-assertion-error-on-stale-data

Comment: I know, it's something with the library (SVPullToRefresh). That's what I want to figure out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43438/discussion-between-ldindu-and-guilherme)

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: @user1688346, if I'm not wrong, I used one of the many forks that fixed this issue. The main repo hasn't been updated in quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [_collection.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]
}
```

What we are doing here is, when we have more data to be rendered, we invalidate the current collection view layout as it will not work with new data and the collection view will layout itself with new available data.