# What exactly happens in a UICollectionViewFlowLayout when dragging a cell using IOS 11 Drag&Drop feature?

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to implement Drag&Drop for my `UICollectionViews` (and also I want to learn about `UICollectionViewLayout`s). I implemented the `dragDelegate/dropDelegate` methods for the collection view and now I can drag cells around.

I also set the drop proposal's intent to `.insertAtDestinationIndexPath`, so that the cells move to make place for the dragged cell (so the layout changes when hovering a dragged cell over it).

This is working perfectly with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. However, I'm using `IGListKit` which basically uses a section for every cell in the collection view. And sections normally always render on a new line, but I want to have multiple sections (=cells) on the same line. That's why I'm subclassing the layout:

```
class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
}

fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
        return 0
    }
    let insets = collectionView.contentInset
    return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
}

var cachedAttribtues = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()
    cachedAttribtues = []
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
    let sectionCount = collectionView.numberOfSections

    var columnWidth = contentWidth / 2 - 5

    var yOffset: CGFloat = 0
    var column = 0

    for section in 0..<sectionCount {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)

        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        attributes.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(column) * columnWidth, y: yOffset, width: columnWidth, height: 150)

        yOffset += CGFloat(column) * 200
        column = (column + 1) % 2


        cachedAttribtues.append(attributes)
    }

}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    for attributes in cachedAttribtues {
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
            visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }

    return visibleLayoutAttributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cachedAttribtues[indexPath.section]
}
}
```

*It's not pretty, it's not optimal, it's just to test things*. My problem now is that it crashes when I drag a cell and move it around:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

I have absolutely no idea what happens here and why. There's something that changes when the cells try to move (to make place for the dragged cell that's hovering above).

It would be awesome if someone could tell me what I need to take care of when I want to support dragging cells with my custom layout. I watched pretty much all of the WWDC sessions on Drag&Drop but I can't find a solution for this.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
I found out something. Inside `layoutAttributesForElements(in:)` I constantly print out all visible IndexPaths in the `UICollectionView`. At the beginning, it looks like this:

> [[0, 0], [2, 0], [1, 0], [3, 0]]

Right before the app crashes, it looks like this:

> [[0, 1], [2, 0], [0, 0], [3, 0]]

So I think the problem is this: In `prepare()`, I create `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for all sections at index 0. So when I pass the attributes that are in the given `CGRect`, it will return `section 1, item 0`, but that doesn't exist, as it somehow became `section 0, item 1` (I think).

So somehow the system wants to place a cell inside section 0 at item 1. Why is that? And what can I do with that information?

Comment: Did you try one of these workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27515673/1506363

Comment: I've seen it, but unfortunately it's a different situation and not applicable here

Comment: IGListKit at some point also had this bug reported: https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/issues/813

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but it's also unrelated, unfortunately.