# UICollectionView doesn't render cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my view I have a `UITableView` which contains cells with horizontal `UICollectionView` inside. The problem is that sometimes `UICollectionViewCell`s are not rendered on device/simulator. At the same time I can see those cells in the View Hierarchy Debugger:

What I see in the View Hierarchy Debugger:
[image]

What I see on a device:
[image]

As you can see, cells (with images) exist and have correct frames and content (proved by the View Hierarchy Debugger). Nevertheless they are not rendered on device/simulator for some reason. What could be the cause of that and how could I fix it?

UPD: another example with "3D" view and bug on one cell, but not on the other

device screenshot:
[image]

view hierarchy debugger:
[image]

Comment: did you add delegates and datasoruce from storyboard

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya of course i did, have you read the whole question?

Comment: yes you have problem with when you run application at debug mode you got your cell but when its run normally it can not show in simulor right

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Not sure if I've got your comment correctly, but even in non-debug mode (debug executable unchecked, configuration set to release, etc) bug persists

Comment: brother did you upload one more screen shot with 3D view that show your all view

Comment: brother like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/lay4hrgwrs0gxms/Screen%20Shot%202017-05-29%20at%206.18.35%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya question updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145377/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-fyodor-volchyok).

Comment: Are you doing some work on background threads/queues? Updating views from other threads than the main thread can cause those changes to stay invisible on the device.

Comment: @Sven unlikely but possible. I'll check as soon as possible and update question. thanks

Comment: please let me know if my solution worked for your or not .... ?? @FyodorVolchyok

Comment: @Sven I double-checked the thread which updates views. It's always the main thread (ui thread).

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that my particular problem is related to [UICollectionView assertion error on stale data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339030/uicollectionview-assertion-error-on-stale-data) because sometimes mentioned crash happens. Playing around `[collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]` I finally fixed this.

Just to record what was NOT the cause (and what you should check if faced with the same problem):

1. check if you update views in the main thread only
2. check if all autolayout constants are set correctly and don't conflict
3. check that your custom views' intrinsic content sizes are calculated correctly

If none of the above is the cause of issue try `invalidateLayout` somewhere around `reloadData` or inside of `layoutSubviews` or similar method.

Comment: Note about bounty: the question why views are visible in the View Hierarchy Debugger but not on a device or simulator is still open. Those who provide answer will be rewarded.