# How to return numberOfItemsInSection for two collectionView?

Tags: uicollectionview

My issues is that I am using the below code to return an images in collection view. ImageArray should return different number of images and claimImageArray should return different number of Images.But it does not work properly .Because it only display one image. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong in this ??

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       if (collectionView==beforeParcelCollectionViews)
        {
             return [imageArray count];
        }
        if (collectionView ==  afterParcelCollectionView)
        {
            return [claimImagesArray count];
        }
           return 0;
    }
```

Comment: can you please provide the property declaration for beforeParcelCollectionViews and afterParcelCollectionView

Comment: UICollectionView *beforeParcelCollectionViews;
    UICollectionView *afterParcelCollectionView;

Comment: I guess beforeParcelCollectionViews and afterParcelCollectionView both have  a null value. Please put a breakpoint and check this.

Comment: According to you beforeParcelCollectionViews and afterParcelCollectionView ... what does it contain so that it work properly ?

Comment: After adding breakpoint on beforeParcelCollectionViews and afterParcelCollectionView . i checked out that it contains UICollectionView.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code or the answer below. Your arrays must be having only 1 element each.

Comment: @Nishant I have checked my arrays count by NSLog.. They both have different images. But they return only one image.

Comment: @NishaGupta: Then the issue might be with the flow layout of the collection view which allows only 1 image. Not sure though due to lack to code.

Comment: @Nishant.. Ohkiee i will recheck the flow layout

Comment: @Nishant .. There is no mistake in flow layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
       if (collectionView==beforeParcelCollectionViews)
       {
         return [imageArray count];
       }
       else if (collectionView ==  afterParcelCollectionView)
       {
         return [claimImagesArray count];
       }
       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem. The following link solved my problem. I think you may set the same flow layout for both collectionView.

[Multiple UICollectionView in one controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850396/multiple-uicollectionview-in-one-controller)